# Automatic indent on text wrap whenever it do not fit one line

Tags: pdftex, line-breaking

Hi guys I am quite new to Latex but I cannot find answer with  Google so I would be grateful for help:

I would like to create rule for LaTex where whenever text do not fit the line and wraps to the new one there is automatically intend made like on the picture below:

[image]

I will be grateful for help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `description` environment might come in handy:

[image]

To customize indentation, spacing, ... take a look at the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just used for dummy text via the \lipsum command. Do not use in real document.
\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{description}
\item[Nominal scale] \lipsum[5]
\end{description}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```